# Responsividade de sites de acordo com o Browser

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3

Eu sei que é um assunto massante e facilmente pode passar por duplicada, mas antes de apontar, leia.

As propriedades do *BootsTraps* não se aplicam ao Browser **Safari** ?

Tenho uma aplicação que em 3 Browser (Chrome, FireFox e Edge) funcionam noralmente, mas testando no Safari fica totalmente desalinhada.

Exemplo:

**Google Chrome** **1366 x 768** (NoteBook) :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Safari** **1366 x 768** (NoteBook):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eis minhas dúvidas.

Seria melhor identificar o Browser sendo acessado via *JavaScript* utilizando os comandos  `navigator.appName` && `navigator.appVersion` e, assim, setar as propriedades do `.CSS` equivalente?

Seria melhor fazer tudo via `.CSS` para deixar dinâmico independente do Browser e/ou resolução da tela?

Obs. A aplicação foi acessada na resolução de **1366 x 768** (NoteBook) e **1600 x 900** (Desktop).

Comment: Vc está usando o Safari no Windows oi no Mac? Se vc está usando o Safari do Windowns essa versão e velha demais, não se preocupe com isso. Tente testar no Safari que seja mais novo. O Bootstrap 3 tem o Grid baseado em Floats, e deveria ser responsivo mesmo em browsers mais antigos, já o Flex e outros estilos do CSS3 podem falhar nessas versões mais antigas do Safari, assim como na última versão do Safari para Windows que é de 2012!!

Comment: Ótima observação @hugocsl, mas, sabe dizer se o Igor informou a versão do Safari, ou se foi testado no Windows?

Comment: @AndréFilipe não sei dizer... ele nunca deu retorno disso

Comment: Pior que é um usuário ativo com visto por último: *5 horas atrás*. Poderiam ao menos dar um retorno com quem tem a maior boa vontade de ajudar.

Comment: Sobre esse caso, o problema era da versão do Safari. Por estar usando no S.O Windowns, instalei a primeira que achei e mesma era antiga. Fiz o testei em um MacBook e o laytout se manteve estável e responsivo... No caso a versão do Mac era a mais atual.